# Visual selection in Nvim-R plugin sends one line too much to terminal

Tags: terminal, neovim, tmux

I have just set up the [Nvim-R](https://github.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R) plugin for `Neovim` to send lines of code from an `.R`-file opened with `Neovim` to a terminal inside a `tmux` session.

Previously, I have worked with its predecessor [Vim-R](https://github.com/jcfaria/Vim-R-plugin), which is no longer being maintained.

In the old `Vim-R`, it was easy to send a visually selected block of code to the terminal by pressing the `r` key while in visual mode after adding the following line to my `.vimrc`:

```
let g:vimrplugin_map_r = 1
```

However, this feature seems to be deprecated in the new `Nvim-R`-plugin. As a workaround I have tried to add the following line to my `.vimrc`:

```
vmap <Space> <Plug>RDSendSelection
```

This actually allows me to send a visually selected section to the terminal, however, it always includes the next non-empty line after the selection, which is irritating. This is especially so, because it even ignores multiple blank lines.

How can I modify this behavior?

Comment: I think you should ask the question to the plugin's developer, https://github.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R/issues/new

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I will try that, too and update this post if I get a reply.

Comment: If you got an answer and your problem is solved, consider adding an answer to this question for further reference ;)

Comment: I don't think this is worth to be posted as an answer since it was just an issue with trailing spaces in my `.vimrc` file. However, another user had the same issue, hence I'll leave the [link](https://github.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R/issues/61#issuecomment-217409723) to the issue discussion on Github.